# Having an initially blank item in ComboBox DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a `ComboBox`, which uses a list as a `DataSource`. As I initially want the selected `ComboBox` item to be blank, I add a blank row to the start of the list, which I then want to remove once the first `SelectedIndexChanged` occurs.

The problem is, that I can manage to remove the blank item again, once added. It seems to be removed from the `DataSource` (tested with `Console.WriteLine(DataSourceList[0].ToString());`), but it remains an option in the `ComboBox`. What the duck am I doing wrong?

**Initial binding**

```
// Set the data source + 1 blank spot
cboDropDown.DataSource = viewModel.dataList;
viewModel.dataList.Insert(0, String.Empty);

// Bind the selected value
Binding bindSelItem = new Binding("SelectedItem", viewModel, "selectedItem");
cboDropDown.DataBindings.Add(bindSelItem);
```

**Selected index changed**

```
private void cboDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Write the first element to the console (debug purpose)
    Console.WriteLine("First element is: " + viewModel.dataList[0].ToString());

    // If the first element is blank, remove and reset datasource
    if (viewModel.dataList[0].ToString() == String.Empty)
    {
        // Remove item at index 0
        viewModel.dataList.RemoveAt(0);

        // Write to console to confirm that it is removed
        Console.WriteLine("First element is: " + viewModel.dataList[0].ToString());

        // Reset data source for ComboBox
        cboDropDown.DataSource = viewModel.dataList;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like the problem is somewhat connected to the fact that `SelectedIndexChanged` is called by the binding procedure itself. I expected it to be called for the first time, when the user changed to ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution. It required two structural changes:

1. Using `BindingList<T>` rather than `List<T>`
2. Use an event which isn't called in the binding procedure (i used `_DropDown`)

So enden up adding a blank item, when the list is created (`.Insert()` is fine as well):

```
BindingList<String> ComboOpts = new BindingList<String>();
comboOpts.Add(String.Empty);
comboOpts.Add("Option 1");
comboOpts.Add("Option 2");
comboOpts.Add("Option 3");
```

And then on the `DropDown` event remove the first item if it is blank. It isn't even nessesary to re-bind the datasource (`BindingList` takes care of that):

```
private void cboMyComboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The first time that the combo box is activated, remove the initial item
    if (viewModel.ComboOptions[0].ToString() == String.Empty)
        viewModel.ComboOptions.RemoveAt(0);                       
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to `DataBind()` your DropDownList after you change its data source.

Comment: Winforms combobox has no DataBind